# Ansible execution using variables

Tags: ansible

hi I want to execute "java -jar xxxxxxx.war 172.xx.xxx.xx" command on a host.
I am able to execute in a single system through Ansible, but I want to execute that command in a multiple hosts and that execution needs to be done in their respective system IP's.

eg:

```
java -jar xxxxxxx.war 172.xx.xxx.01 needs to be executed on the system with the IP 172.xx.xxx.01

java -jar xxxxxxx.war 172.xx.xxx.02 needs to be executed on the system with the IP 172.xx.xxx.02

- name: Executing the jar file
  win_shell: "CMD /C \"java -jar generateKeyStoreFiles.jar storeipTest.csv\""
  args:
   chdir: C:/Keystore_Pem_FileAutoGenerationOracle_allgoodthings/
- name: Copying of Xstore POS Installer
  win_copy:
   src: /root/Installers/Softwares/Xstore
   dest: C:/Installers/Softwares/
- name: Copying of xstore_mobile.keystore file
  win_copy:
   src: C:/Keystore_Pem_FileAutoGenerationOracle_allgoodthings/finalcerts/cert/xstore_mobile.keystore
   dest: C:/Installers/Softwares/Xstore/
   remote_src: yes
- name: install Xstore POS
  win_shell: "CMD /C \"java -jar xstore-18.0.0.0.654-0.0.0-0.0-XST-pos-install.jar\""
  args:
   chdir: C:/Installers/Softwares/Xstore/
```

how is that possible ?, I need to execute that on windows hosts.

Comment: You have to create a group with the required hosts. After that you apply your play-book to the group.

Comment: Have you written an Ansible command or playbook for that? If yes, please share it in the description.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create an inventory and a playbook to achieve that.

*inventory*

```
[all]
13.48.139.217
13.48.139.218
```

*playbook.yml*

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: run java command
      command: java -jar xxxxxxx.war {{ansible_host}}
```

`{{ansible_host}}` is an Asnsible variable that will be replaced with an IP address mentioned in inventory.
Then execute it `ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml`.

Comment: but what is the proof that the command with the ip address will reach that respective system ? Will that work ? and also that command will generate some keys. will the keys generated by that particular ip will be stored in that respective ip address system ?

Comment: Please update the question if you need additional functionality. My answer was related to your question at the time it was asked.